# Application Wrapper for Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I work with Excel pretty much all day every day.  There are a few spreadsheets I have that I use almost like stand-alone applications.  My problem is that I often have 10 or 20 other spreadsheets open and sometimes they will crash.  Unless I was very careful to keep my application-like excel spreadsheets in different instances, they will crash too.

I understand that I can achieve what I want if I am careful, but I am looking for a way to achieve this without having to think about it or be careful.  I often open my timesheet in one instance and then a bunch of others in another instance, but I might forget and just double-click a few from the file explorer and then they are open in my timesheet app.

Is there a way to launch a spreadsheet in a new instance and not allow any other spreadsheets to be opened in that instance?  Even better would be a simple wrapper program that let me create "apps" out of certain Excel files - such that I could just click on the app and it would open up the spreadsheet in an instance that was completely standalone and unable to open other spreadsheets?

EDIT: I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: What version of excel? DDE is the answer here.